# Cant convert enum type to short and vice versa

Tags: java, enums

In one class I have this code

```
public class RPCMessage implements Serializable{
 public static final short REQUEST = 0;
 public static final short REPLY = 1;
 public enum MessageType{REQUEST, REPLY};
 private MessageType messageType;

 public MessageType getMessageType() {
     return messageType;
 }
 public void setMessageType(MessageType messageType) {
     this.messageType = messageType;
 }
}
```

I another class I try to access it but it gives me error there.
Error Code:

```
int buffSize = c.lenInBytes();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffSize);
        short typeNum = (short) c.getMessageType();
        int index = 0;
        bb.putShort(0,typeNum);
        index+=2;
```

Also error in setting the same attribute

```
RPCMessage c = new RPCMessage();
              ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(mData);
              int index = 0;

              c.setMessageType(bb.getShort(index));
              index += 2;
```

I am quite new to Java programming. Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the relation between RPCMessage and MessageType? You have created "c" of type RPCMessage and trying to use setter of MessageType.

Can you please post required code?

Comment: @Suyash I have edited the code. RPCMessage is the class in which MessageType is an enum

Comment: You need to read a basic tutorial on Java enums.

Comment: Please don't ignore your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is not appropriate in your case.

I will try to elaborate the use of Enums :
Your `RPCMessage` class should be something like :

```
public class RPCMessage implements Serializable {
    //public static final short REQUEST = 0; // Not required
    //public static final short REPLY = 1; // Not required

    public enum MessageType {
        REQUEST((short)0),

        REPLY((short)1);

        private short enumVar;

        private MessageType(short var){
            enumVar = var;
        }
    };


    private MessageType messageType;

    public MessageType getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }

    public void setMessageType(MessageType messageType) {
        this.messageType = messageType;
    }


}
```

Your second snippet should look like :

```
//int buffSize = c.lenInBytes();
//ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffSize);
short typeNum = (short) c.getMessageType().enumVar; // Only tested this line 
//int index = 0;
//bb.putShort(0,typeNum);
//index+=2;
```

Your third snippet  should look like :

```
RPCMessage c = new RPCMessage();
//ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(mData);
//int index = 0;
//c.setMessageType(bb.getShort(index)); 
c.setMessageType(MessageType.REPLY); // You can change this line as per your need
//index += 2;
```

To test the enum I have used below main function in `RPCMessage` class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RPCMessage c = new RPCMessage();
    //int buffSize = 0;
    c.setMessageType(MessageType.REPLY);
    //ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffSize);
    short typeNum = (short) c.getMessageType().enumVar;
    //int index = 0;
    //bb.putShort(0,typeNum);
    //index+=2;

    System.out.println(typeNum);
}
```

Please note that the above answer will need appropriate changes as per your need.
I have provided just the part related to `enum` to let you understand it in easy way.
There are more eloquent ways to use the `enum`.

For more details on enum please check :
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/how-and-when-to-use-enums-and-annotations.html

In case you are wondering between use of enum vs constants you can refer :
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125415/best-practice-for-constant-class-in-java/125416#125416